# Is it possible to transform the pseudo-elements of individual items inside a CSS grid on hover?

Tags: css, css-grid

## I'm trying to transform the pseudo-elements of individual grid items when I hover over them

I have tried to transform the height of the pseudo-elements associated with individual grid items from 0 to 100% any time I hover over the grid items. The desired effect is that the pseudo-element drops down from the top and completely covers individual grid items on hover, but I can't get it to work. This is how I've tried to do this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 180px));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, 180px);
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 200px 0 100px 0;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: white;
  border: white 10px solid;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  background-color: brown;
}

.grid-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.grid-item:hover .grid-item::before {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: @BrunoSdoukos I changed my original class names to make this post easier to read. The 'menu-grid-item' class was left by mistake. I have edited the question to make things consistent. Also, I have run the code again but I'm still facing the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `.grid-item:hover .grid-item::before`

Which expects a grid item inside the hovered item e.g.:

```
<div class="grid-item"> <!-- If this is hovered -->
  <div class="grid-item"></div> <!-- Pseudo element styles will affect this element -->
</div>
```

If you want to select the pseudo element on the item you are hovering:

`.grid-item:hover::before`

Working example:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 180px));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, 180px);
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 200px 0 100px 0;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: white;
  border: white 10px solid;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  background-color: brown;
}

.grid-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.grid-item:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>

</div>
```